# C, JSON (Jansson) and some autotools build issues

Tags: c, json

I am working on a program that historically used a flat file text format to store its preferences, however I wish to switch to using a library to offload all that custom code. I have a fondness for json and I've been looking at jansson.

I haven't been having much luck though, what I have done is first put a check in my configure.ac file checking for the json_string function in the libjansson package.

```
...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for vte_terminal_fork_command in -lvte... yes
checking for json_string in -ljansson... yes
...
```

As you can see, that works, the problem is that I get the following error when I run make:

```
/home/niadh/Projects/x2/code/src/libX2.h:22: undefined reference to `json_string'
```

I am running the latest Ubuntu and installed the libjansson4 and libjansson-dev packages, if anyone can help me get up and running with this I'd be grateful. If I have failed to provide critical information please do let me know, I shall endeavour to provide further information. I'm also more than expecting that it's something simple that I have missed, if so I apologise in advance.

For convenience, here is the libX2.h file that the error occurred in.

```
#include <jansson.h>

static gchar *getConfigDir() {
  return g_build_filename(g_get_home_dir(), ".config", "X2", NULL);
}

static gchar *getConfigFile() {
  return g_build_filename(getConfigDir(), "X2.conf", NULL);
}

static gchar *getTemplatesDir() {
  return g_build_filename(getConfigDir(), "templates", NULL);
}

static gchar *getTemplate(gchar *template) {
  return g_build_filename(getTemplatesDir, template, NULL);
}

static gchar *getDefaultPreferences() {
  const gchar *font = "Sans 10";
  const gchar *tabs = "bottom";
  json_t *nothing = json_string("testing");
  /*json_t *programmingFeatures = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *syntaxHighlighting = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *lineNumbering = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *highlightLine = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *terminal = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *searchInWords = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *caseSensitiveSearch = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *lineWrapping = json_boolean(1);
  json_t *fontInfo = json_string(font);
  json_t *tabsPosition = json_string(tabs);*/
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a build issue, I had not edited my make file correctly, answering so that it doesn't remain unanswered for the frustration of any potential future readers.